# Seeking an elegant way for inherited classes to have a "StateName" property

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, macros, types

### See my solution below -- search for UPDATE.

I have an extensive state machine architecture, which I'm implementing by creating a class for each state (there are multiple machines, but the states for all inherit from the same 'MachineState' class).  Each state has a static property "StateName":

```
public class SomeState: MachineState
{

  // THIS BLOCK SHOULD BE COPIED TO ALL STATE CLASSES!!
  private static string _StateName;
  public static string StateName
  { 
     get {
           if (_StateName == null)
           { 
               _StateName = MethodBase
                  .GetCurrentMethod()
                  .DeclaringType
                  .ToString()
                  .Split(new char[] { '.' })
                  .ToList()
                  .Last();
           }
           return _StateName; 
          }  
  }
  // END OF BLOCK


  public SomeState(Queue<string> messages)  // 
        : base(messages)
  {
       ...
  }
...
}
```

Ugh.

At least I'll call the processor-intensive stuff to get the name only once per class -- for my purposes, that's an acceptable cost.  But I would really like to find some way for them to "inherit" this code -- or at least some way for them to include it something like a macro.  I have an abstract property, so if it's not implemented I'll catch it at compile time; but still, there's got to be a way to avoid copying that mess into EVERY class -- and then having to CHANGE it in every class if the need ever arises.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

------------  UPDATE ---------------------------------------

Life is full of compromises; this one I can live with.  @Tallek suggested this in the base class:

```
 public static string GetStateName<T>() where T : MachineState
    {
        return typeof(T).Name;
    }
```

I integrated that with my static property, like this (for class 'SomeState'):

```
    // THIS BLOCK SHOULD BE COPIED TO ALL STATE CLASSES!!
    public static string StateName { get { return GetStateName<SomeState>(); } }
```

It isn't perfect; I'll have to be sure to get the correct state name in the GetStateName call for each class.  But it does two things I was anxious to do: it moves the logic into a single location, and it is easier to read.  Keeping StateName abstract will help me catch any state that hasn't implemented StateName.

Thanks again, to all.

Comment: Does it need to be `static`?  If not then it _will_ get inherited.

Comment: Yes; I'm trying to avoid an enormous enum or zillions of const strings to identify state names, so I want each state to be identifiable (as a string... this is necessary).  So I want to be able to access the states like this:

    if(stateName == SomeState.StateName)
    {
    }

Comment: `public string StateName { get { return GetType().Name; } }`?

Comment: @CodeCaster someone needed to say that

Comment: GetType requires me to instantiate the class.

To be more clear, I've got switch statements in each machine that will check to see what the current state is, and -- based upon messages received -- take the correct action.  I don't want to have to instantiate 20 or 30 classes to get their StateNames.

Comment: Then show the code where you access this property, it's not clear to me what you are trying to do with this property value. You may want to do it the other way around, using a factory and a switch or dictionary, like `case "SomeState": return new SomeState();`.

Comment: It seems like this is an abuse of `static`. Consider approaching the problem differently: every `MachineState` should have an explicitly created instance, and you can get the name of the state from that instance.

Comment: asawyer, I just saw your message; MachineState is my own class.

Comment: Could do a static method on the base class, GetStateName<T>() where T : MachineState and return typeof(T).Name;

Comment: if(state.GetType() == typeof(SomeState))

Comment: @Timothy Shields, opinions may vary, but I don't believe it's an abuse of the static.  Each class needs to have this property; and it will be immutable from the first call to the last.  I'm concerned about the discipline of requiring every class to have a unique name typed into it (realistically, cut-and-paste is what is most likely to be abused here).

But I've spent a couple of days now trying to figure out a way to do this, and I'm stumped.  So I'll probably wind up doing that.

Comment: @MeirionHughes, I can't afford to query the system for state types constantly; I need to get the name once and keep it as a property of the class.

Comment: @Tallek, That just might work.  I'll give it a shot!  Thanks.

Seriously, thank you all.  All of your suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: @JoeBaker The reason I'm saying it's a problem is as follows. Suppose I give you a `List<MachineState> L`. How do you get the names of the states in `L`?  It seems completely natural to me to want to do this: `L.Select(state => state.StateName)`. But you can't do that if `StateName` is `static`. When things are `static`, the only straightforward way to get at them is to actually refer to them by the class name directly in code, rather than via a more-programmatic interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not great, but maybe worth considering...

```
public class MachineState
{
   public static string GetStateName<T>() where T : MachineState
   {
       return typeof(T).Name;
   }
```

}

Use like this:

```
if("MyState" == MachineState.GetStateName<MyState>()) { ... }
```

Comment: Ok, I see now what you were talking about in your comment above.  I'll have to do some experimenting.  I think if I make the method compile inline, it might be acceptable performance.  It'll still have to call typeof(T) on every comparison -- which is a lot.  I'd much rather just grab a static string off of the heap.  But this is much more elegant than anything else I've considered.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. As far as typeof() goes though, I believe that is resolved at compile time. I wouldn't think you would take a run time performance hit from that.

Answer (score 1):

- You have a state
- Your states are classes
- You want to compare that state to another
- You don't want to instanciate states in order to compare

I don't see you doing it easier than:

```
if(state.GetType() == typeof(SomeState))
```

Comment: Again, when I do the comparison what I actually have is a message containing a state name -- not an instantiated state.  The name I have is actually the state that the machine is requested to go to, not the current state.  It arrives in a message Queue from the application that is controlling the machine -- which I would also like to be able to access the name via "SomeState.StateName".

Comment: In future, use numbers; if you can create a class you can create an enum member to go with it... you cannot do better than that for performance.

Answer (score 1):

I potentially agree with CodeCaster.  20 or 30 states is not that large for an enum.

Based on your description of receiving a message and identifying the handler for that message, combined with looking at your example:

```
if(stateName == SomeState.StateName) { }
```

This implies you have `stateName` as a parameter.  So you have an if block for every state so you can identify which one the message applies to?

```
if(stateName == SomeState.StateName) { 

}
if(stateName == OtherState.StateName) { 

}
```

***If that is the case...***
 (big if given limited use case information, the rest of this answer is based on that premise so don't flame me if the rest of this doesn't apply)

You desire to have all classes automatically have this StateName property.  This seems DRY, but then we see you still have to have an if block for each state, which is less DRY since there's more code to that IMO.  You've traded a DRY for another DRY.

I would have enums which each have a

```
public enum States {
...
[Handler(typeof(SomeState))]
SomeState = 5,
...
```

Combined with a factory pattern, and now you throw out all the if blocks and only need a call to your factory:

```
MachineState newState = StateFactory.Create(stateName);
```

The factory uses `Enum.Parse` to convert the stateName into an enum, from which you access the attribute to get the type you need to instantiate.  ***No switch/case/if/else needed.***

This means every time you implement a new state class, you only need to touch one place, and that is the enum, and that has minimal code repetition.

**If each if block has specific logic in it for that particular State**
Move that code into a HandleMessage method defined in a MachineState or IMachineState interface, which has an implementation for each SomeState to do the stuff specific for that state.  Let's assume your message indicates the stateName and maybe there's some "content" or "data" in the message that needs to be processed:

```
MachineState newState = StateFactory.Create(stateName);
newState.HandleMessage(messageContent);
```

I realize it's probably more complicated than that.  You might need to seperate state from state handling into separate classes to make this work well.  It's hard say.  I would certainly mull this over pretty heavily though if I were in your shoes.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not a hardcore C# guy, and this factory business is not something I've messed with; it sounds like a great opportunity to play with it.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, 20 or 30 would be the enum for each machine.  I'm modeling a complex system that will eventually have dozens of machines; so I'm looking for ways to simplify or standardize whereever I can.  Anything that can be inherited is of tremendous value to me, because it will save me doing int hundreds of times.  Even something as simple as creating an enum value, I'd rather not do if I can help it.

Comment: @JoeBaker That implies you are repeating code of the form `if(stateName == *State.StateName) {` hundreds of times? I prefer to do away with these kinds of lists of if's/switch/cases and use a common interface and have each State class express its own behavior such as HandleMessage.  When you copy paste that if block, to support a new State class, there's the potential you might miss changing the class name in some part of it, assuming you also have a `new SomeState` somewhere in there that must also be changed. If you did the same with a new enum value the compiler will catch this duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with an extension method:

```
public static string GetStateName(this MachineState state) {

  return state.GetType().Name;

}
```

Use it like this:

```
if(state.GetStateName() == "SomeState") { /* Do something */ }
```

Bake in your own caching if you want: you have access to any static structures you want here.